# How can i enlarge image in matlab without using matlab imresize function

Tags: matlab

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2OSx.png)i am not getting the proper results kindly share your code

```
enter code here
a=imread('rice.png')
[rows,columns]=size(a);
i=1; j=1;
c=zeros(rows*4,columns);
for x=1:2;rows
for y=1:2:columns
c(i,j)=a(x,y);
j=j+1;
end
i=i+1;
j=1;
end
figure,imshow(a);
figure,imshow(c/255);
figure,imagesc(c),colormap(gray);
```

I am using this code its not giving me proper results

Comment: It looks like you need to step through your script using the debugger so that you can see the values as they change and figure out when they deviate from what you expect, starting with the size of the image `c`. If you start out with a 100x100 image, do you really want to resize to a 400x100 image?

Comment: i only want to double the size from original size

Comment: `for x=1:2;rows` has a typo, you need to use `:`, not `;`.

Comment: its still not working :( @Cris Luengo

Comment: I know, that was one of the issues. beaker mentioned another. You're also only reading 1/4 of the input pixels, not sure why. In any case "share your code" is not a question, and "not giving me proper results" is not a useful problem statement. As per [ask] and [mcve], you need to provide a clear problem statement: Why do you think your output is wrong? What did you expect? Why can't you use `imresize`? Can you use `interp2`? etc.

Comment: @WajihaAslamMalik If you want to double the size, then first create a new image that is double the size of the original. Is that what `c=zeros(...)` does in your script? No. So fix this line, then move on to the next one. Does that do what you want it to do? No, so fix that and then keep going.

Answer (score -1):

you should check original image's type and need to create same type image. Following code would help you to understand the logic behind expanding an image.
Let's say your image's (1,1) pixel value is 128, in here we are writing that value to (1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2) pixels.

```
clear;clc;close all;
A=imread('rice.png'); % read the image
[rows, columns]=size(A); % get size of the image
m=2;      % Expanding ratio (you can change that value to whatever you want)
newA=zeros(rows*2, columns*2,'uint8'); %new created image should be in same
for i=1:columns                        %type with original image.
    for j=1:rows                       
        newA(i*m,j*m)=A(i,j);          % Writing pixel values on (2,2),(2,4),(4,2),(4,4),...
        newA((i*m)-1,(j*m)-1)=A(i,j);  % Writing pixel values on (1,1),(1,3),(3,1),(3,3),...
        newA((i*m),(j*m)-1)=A(i,j);    % Writing pixel values on (2,1),(2,3),(4,1),(4,3),...
        newA((i*m)-1,(j*m))=A(i,j);    % Writing pixel values on (1,2),(1,4),(3,2),(3,4),...
    end
end
```

Comment: I did not downvote, but I agree this is not a good answer. The code you post is an example of bad MATLAB code, and there are no explanations on why it works. Note that you don’t need to loop in MATLAB for what you do here, and the code would be much more efficient and easier to read without the loops.

Comment: Try this: `newA(1:m:end,1:2:end)=A`.